# How can I programatically reigster request methods (GET/POST/PUT) in Jersey, without using annotations?

Tags: jersey

How can I programatically reigster request methods (GET/POST/PUT) in Jersey, without using annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in Jersey 1.x. Hopefully coming in JAX-RS and Jersey 2.0.